# Android camera2 preview image disorder when saved using ImageReader

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am taking a series of pictures using Android Camera2 API for real time pose estimation and environment reconstruction (the SLAM problem). Currently I simply save all of these pictures in my SD card for off-line processing.

I setup the processing pipeline according to google's `Camera2Basic` using a `TextureView` as well as an `ImageReader`, where they are both set as target surfaces for a repeat preview request.

```java
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(mIsShooting){
                    try {
                        mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
                        mPreviewRequestBuilder.removeTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
                        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                        mIsShooting = false;
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    try {
                        mCaptureSession.stopRepeating();
                        mPreviewRequestBuilder.addTarget(mImageReader.getSurface());
                        mCaptureSession.setRepeatingRequest(mPreviewRequestBuilder.build(), mCaptureCallback, mBackgroundHandler);
                        mIsShooting = true;
                    } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

The `ImageReader` is added/removed when pressing the button. The `ImageReader`'s `OnImageAvailableListener` is implemented as follow:

```java
private ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            Image img = reader.acquireLatestImage();
            if(null == img){
                return;
            }
            if(img.getTimestamp() <= mLatestFrameTime){
                Log.i(Tag, "disorder detected!");
                return;
            }
            mLatestFrameTime = img.getTimestamp();
            ImageSaver saver = new ImageSaver(img, img.getTimestamp());
            saver.run();
        }
    };
```

I use `acquireLatestImage` (with buffer size set to 2) to discard old frames and have also checked the image's timestamp to make sure they are monotonously increasing.

The reader does receive images at an acceptable rate (about 25fps). However a closer look at the saved image sequence show they are not 
always saved in chronological order.

The following pictures come from a long sequence shot by the program (sorry for not being able to post pictures directly :( ):

Image 1:

[image: https://github.com/thuliangjz/openfile/blob/master/pic01218.jpg]

Image 2:

[image: https://github.com/thuliangjz/openfile/blob/master/pic01219.jpg]

Image 3:

[image: https://github.com/thuliangjz/openfile/blob/master/pic01218.jpg]

Such disorder does not occur very often but they can occur any time and seems not to be an initialization problem. I suppose it has something to do with the `ImageReader`'s buffer size as with larger buffer less "flash backs" are occurred. Does anyone have the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally find that such disorder disappears when setting `ImageReader`'s format to be `YUV_420_888` in its constructor. Originally I set this field as `JPEG`.

Using `JPEG` format incurs not only large processing delay but also disorder. I guess the conversion from image sensor data to desired format utilizes other hardware  such as DSP or GPU which does not guarantee chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using TEMPLATE_STILL_CAPTURE for the capture requests when you enable the ImageReader, or just TEMPLATE_PREVIEW?  What devices are you seeing issues with?

If you're using STILL_CAPTURE, make sure you check if the device supports the [ENABLE_ZSL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CaptureRequest.html#CONTROL_ENABLE_ZSL) flag, and set it to false.  When it is set to true (generally the default on devices that support it, for the STILL_CAPTURE template), images may be returned out of order since there's a zero-shutter-lag queue in place within the camera device.

Comment: Thanks for your apply ! However I'm using TEMPLATE_PREVIEW and start a repeated capture session.